# (Mac) Panel Re-size issue

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, interface-builder

I've created an application for Mac that uses a horizontal resize view (technically a BWToolkit resize view) that is linked to a `toggleCollapse` button. After collapsing and expanding the panel a few times, this happens (see image) right table-view should be flush with panel divider. Any one have any info on why this is happening. I've carefully adjusted my alignment and anchors to be correct but it seems like this is a weird issue that bugs out the view?

[image: Table should be flush with panel divider..]

**EDIT:** Is anyone NOT having this issue? Any input would be helpful! Maybe I just need to start fresh?

Comment: Hi Joe, I appreciate the answer but this question only applies to BWToolkit (a framework) SplitViews - not general NSSplitViews. Leaving 5 seconds between each click doesn't change it. Plus, what if a user doesn't wait 5 seconds? Apple will consider this a bug and possibly reject the app for it..

Comment: @Joe: www.brandonwalkin.com/bwtoolkit

Comment: @Joe: Hi, actually BWToolkit is a very well known framework, it's used in a good majority of Mac applications. But yeah a bug is certainly possible in this case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug in BWSplitView itself, and is related to how view animation and timers interact in that view.  The details are covered here:

http://bwalkin.lighthouseapp.com/projects/36323/tickets/34-split-view-doesnt-resize-subview-properly-during-a-toggle-uncollapse-after-manual-collapse

Basically, before the view is animated, autoresizesSubviews is unset, so that the view can be collapsed/expanded without affecting the contents; a timer is then scheduled to restore the autoresizesSubviews property for when the animation has completed.  But (of course) the animation may sometimes finish ever so slightly earlier, or later, than the scheduled timer fires; so autoresizing is switched on before the animation has completed, resulting in a few pixels resize.  As you've probably seen, the subviews tend to move around a bit as the view is collapsed and uncollapsed.

The "full" fix for this would be to restore autoresizing when the CAAnimation has completed using a callback, but this hasn't been implemented yet.  However, in that thread "Robert Payne" has posted a version of BWSplitView.m which uses a slightly different approach - the view sizes are recorded before collapsing, and restored after expanding.  I applied this patch myself (I think it won't compile at first - but it's a simple matter of an undeclared variable?) and can confirm it does fix the problem.

Let me know if you'd like a BWSplitView.m which compiles successfully, or a copy of the compiled framework.

Comment: @Rowan: Thank you man! Very detailed and thorough response. Absolutely, if you can get me some more info on that code file I would be very grateful

Comment: @Zakman411 I've put the (fully) patched BWSplitView.[h|m] files up at http://beent.je/BWSplitView.zip if you prefer to build your own copy of the frameworks - just drop those into the source tree, replacing the current copies.If you'd prefer a compiled copy of the framework, you can download a compiled copy of the framework file itself from http://sequel-pro.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Frameworks/BWToolkitFramework.framework/Versions/A/BWToolkitFramework and drop that in over the current Versions/A copy you have.  (I compiled that for ppc/i386/x86_64 - no 64-bit PPC if you really need that!)

Comment: @Rowan: the compiled framework is a document with no extension - and I don't see how to implement the .m file with the other method (I simply can't find the .m file? Where is it located in the framework?)

Comment: @Zakman411 the compiled framework linked is just the binary part - so you'd drop it into the Framework folder at at Versions/A/BWToolkitFramework.  I thought that was better than a custom zip file, but maybe not :)  As for the .m file - that's for use with the source code if you'd prefer to compile your own version, available at http://www.brandonwalkin.com/bwtoolkit/ . :)

Comment: @Rowan: You mean drop it right onto the 'Frameworks' folder in XCode or find the folder in Finder and drop it there? Sorry, I'm new to this..

Comment: @Zakman411 Let's make this simpler then ;)  You can grab a patched version of the compiled .framework itself from http://beent.je/BWToolkitFramework.framework.1.2.5-patched.zip .  Dropping that into the Frameworks folder should work.

Comment: @Rowan: Thank you so much for putting in the time to help me! I have to add that I'm using the version of BWToolkit that uses no private API's so that it will be accepted in the app store. Is there a way to only replace the files I need, or to compile the non-private API version w/ the fixed files? Here's the non-private API Version. Thanks for sticking with me on this!
http://byteproject.net/post/3016833303/bwtoolkit-1-2-5-w-o-private-api

Comment: @Zakman411 I merged in both sets of patches - give http://beent.je/BWToolkitFramework.framework.1.2.5-noprivate-patched.zip a go, although I haven't tested it myself :)